# how to assign multiple paths to Route?

Tags: reactjs

```
          <Route exact path={"/" || "/home"}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
```

How can I achieve something like this without having to write another Route just for home?

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of path strings. Remember that path order and specificity typically matter, so list the more specific paths *before* the less specific paths. If you still need to disambiguate the paths, *then* add the `exact` prop.

```
<Route path={["/home", "/"]}>
  <Home />
</Route>
```